# Magento 1.7 Can't add/edit category's

Tags: magento, categories, backend

Since i upgraded my store to 1.7, i can't create new categories and also can't edit them.

I saw some solutions on the internet that said i need to reinstall magento with a clean installation but then i will lose my whole store and things i've added up to now.

has anybody else a better solution?

Comment: This isn't a programming related question so it shouldn't be on Stack Overflow. Try Server Fault instead.

Comment: I already put one there but because nobody was reacting i thought i put it here also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go to catalog -> manage products:

Select all the products you need on your website.

Now from the 'actions' dropdown select 'update attributes'. You have to add them to the store you need them to be on. And save.

Back at catalog -> manage categories and pick a category. Now open the products tab select 'any' and search for the products you want in this category and save.

Visit your frontend to check :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out as below.
Go to Magento Admin >> Magento Connect Manager.

At the Mage_Downloader field,
Click check for Upgrade button.

It will give you some upgrade information.
then select reinstall at the action field that you want to upgrade.

do the upgrade!

Don't fotget Flush the cache & reindex.

I hope it should be helpful for you.